# Testing In Bot Framework Emulator Giving Invalid Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I am currently attempting to run my bot in the bot framework emulator, and when going through my OAuth sign-in process, I am receiving an unusual token. Typically, I receive a token in the form of `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFlOWdkazcifQ...`, but am instead receiving a token in the form of a GUID followed by `|livechat` (e.g. `d135d0c4-b5d8-424d-b922-26ae5c0309f8|livechat`).

This is resulting in my conversations not being able to get past the OAuth prompt stage because my token is never valid.

This problem also coincidentally started occurring when I upgraded my version of Bot Framework Emulator. I have tried downgrading to my previous version, but unfortunately, the problem still persists.

I also receive this additional message that I have never received before when I attempt to click on my signin button within the chat. Here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NsYm.jpg

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in Emulator related to ngrok in Settings, at the moment.

If you uncheck "Bypass ngrok for local addresses", the correct token value is returned. However, if you leave it checked then it is returning the guid + "|livechat" value.

The issue is already being tracked on the BotFramework-Emulator repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1544).

[image]

Comment: I tried unchecking the "Bypass ngrok for local addresses" option, but am still getting the same GUID token response. I even tried restarting the emulator and toggling the "Use a sign-in verification code for OAuthCards" option, and got the same result.

Comment: Is your bot built using the v3 or v4 c# SDK?

Comment: It's using the C# V4 SDK

Comment: Try restarting your bot (and Emulator with the settings as above), as well, in case the (incorrect) token was cached. Can you also provide your code so I can better diagnose what might be happening?

Comment: I tried to restart the bot and emulator, but am still getting an invalid token. I have shared my source code with you via OneDrive.